# Meteor: filtering a complete collection that is published with limit for lazy loading

Tags: meteor

I have a collection of posts that I want to load in chunks aka pagination/lazyloading. But also I want to:

1. search all posts
2. alternatively load and show all posts with an attribute 'important' of that collection without limit.

I didn't get along with multiple collections or subscriptions yet, so instead of setting the limit in .publish() in the server-code, I did it on the client side. Looks like this:

```
// Server side
export const Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('posts', function () {
    return Posts.find({}, {
      sort: {createdAt: -1}
    });
  });
}

//Client side
export default createContainer(() => {
  Session.setDefault('lazyloadLimit', 10);
  Meteor.subscribe('entrys');

  return {
    posts: Posts.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 }, limit: Session.get('lazyloadLimit') }).fetch(),
    importantPosts: Posts.find({important: true}, {sort: { createdAt: -1 }}).fetch(),
    importantPostsCount: Posts.find({important: true}).count(),
  };
}, App);
```

The results look right, but **now my main question is: Does this load all Posts to the client, or just those within the limit?** I guess it loads all of them, making the limit only be of use for the rendering time, but not for the bandwidth.

Just for completenes: My previous attempt looked like this, but I couldn't get to the ImportantPosts-collection:

```
// Server side
export const Posts = new Mongo.Collection('entrys');
export const ImportantPosts = new Mongo.Collection(null); // <- where do I put this?

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('posts', function (limit) {
    return Posts.find({}, {
      limit: limit,
      sort: {createdAt: -1}
    });
  });

  Meteor.publish('importantPosts', function () {
    return Posts.find({important: true}, {
      sort: {createdAt: -1}
    }); // <- how do I get these into ImportantPosts-collection?
  });
}

// Client side
export default createContainer(() => {

  Session.setDefault('lazyloadLimit', 10);
  Tracker.autorun(function(){
    Meteor.subscribe('posts', Session.get('lazyloadLimit'));
  });
  Meteor.subscribe('importantPosts');

  return {
    entrys: Posts.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 }, limit: Session.get('lazyloadLimit') }).fetch(),
    importantPosts: ImportantPosts.find({}, {sort: { createdAt: -1 }}).fetch(),
    importantPostsCount: ImportantPosts.find({}).count(),
  };
}, App);
```

Answer (score 2):

let's talk about what these 2 do, from your earlier attempt, but calling it 'posts':

```
  export const Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');

  Meteor.publish('posts', function (limit) {
    return Posts.find({}, {
      limit: limit,
      sort: {createdAt: -1}
    });
  });

  Meteor.publish('importantPosts', function () {
    return Posts.find({important: true}, {
      sort: {createdAt: -1}
    }); // <- how do I get these into ImportantPosts-collection?
  });
```

the first, clearly, publishes all posts. the second publishes a subset of all the posts. as is, the 2nd is redundant. (from the client, you would do all your processing on the collection 'posts'.) Meteor calls this the "merge box": it combines all published items from the same collection into the same "box". i.e. it's the union of all the publishes from the same collection.

the downside of that first publish is that you are publishing all the posts to all clients just so you can do a search. that could potentially be a lot of data. you already mentioned paging, so conceptually that will help with what you're trying to do.

looking at the code i pasted above, you're thinking of the 2 publish statements as 2 separate collections, when really they're 1. so let's proceed with that in mind.

you want to do all of this:

1. page posts
2. show all important posts
3. search through posts

let's start with #3. i will assert that that should be done on the server. you can write a meteor method to do the search using the user's search term, and that meteor method, instead of returning that data, can simply publish the results. Meteor's merge box will ensure your client now has those posts, in addition to whatever posts it already has.

so upon searching, now your client need merely filter by the search value, and it should just work.

now for #2: you already have the publish written, filtering by important=true. if you subscribe to that on the client, those results are written to the merge box.

that leaves #1, which you already have written. as your user pages through posts, all of those will be written to the merge box.

so your client, in addition to subscribing to 2 things and making a method call, now just has to handle the filtering based on the user either searching, asking to see the important ones, or both (i.e. searches through just the important ones).

and all of these operations will be on the collection 'posts'.

the end result of doing it this way is that instead of loading all the posts at once, you're incrementally loading them as the user pages. so the user won't get all the posts unless they go through all the pages.

Comment: Nicely written answer @zim!

Answer (score 0):

A solution I just found that seems to work (without me understanding how it works) might be [Find From Publication](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/find-from-publication) looking like this:

```
$ meteor add percolate:find-from-publication
```

-

```
// Server side
export const Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('posts', function (limit) {
    return Posts.find({}, {
      limit: limit,
      sort: {createdAt: -1}
    });
  });
  FindFromPublication.publish('importantPosts', function () {
    return Posts.find({important: true}, {
      sort: {createdAt: -1}
    });
  });
}

// Client side
export default createContainer(() => {
  Session.setDefault('lazyloadLimit', 10);
  Tracker.autorun(function(){
    Meteor.subscribe('posts', Session.get('lazyloadLimit'));
  });
  Meteor.subscribe('importantPosts');

  return {
    posts: Posts.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 }, limit: Session.get('lazyloadLimit') }).fetch(),
    importantPosts: Posts.findFromPublication('importantPosts', {}, {sort: { createdAt: -1 }}).fetch(),
    importantPostsCount: Posts.findFromPublication('importantPosts', {}).count(),
  };
}, App);
```